# Is there a way to get the count of objects/files which are older than 60 days using cloudwatch?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I used boto3 client s3 to get a count of files older than 60 days but it takes more than an hour as I have 40TB of data and 0.7 million objects. Is there any way to do this?

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket='mybucket')
...
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this?

Yes. Since you haven't specified that this operation must be in real-time, the best option would be to request [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html). The benefit of this is that you get much more info then only timestamp of your objects, which can be very valuable for further filtering and searching through your objects based on their metadata.